# Comma Delimiting C

Tags: c

I need my program to take a series of file names (stored in a single "String" and separated by commas) and act on them.

The psuedo code would be:

```
for each filename in some_string
    open filename
    operate on contents of filename
    close filename
```

The issue is that I'm stuck separating some_string ("filename1,filename2,...,filenamen") into [filename 1], [filename 2], ... [filename n].

Edit: to clarify, it seems simpler to keep some_string intact and extract each file name as needed, which is what I'm attempting to do.

My code, as it stands, is pretty clunky (and quite disgusting...)

```
int j = 0;
char *tempS = strdup(filenames);
while (strchr(tempS, ',')) {
    char *ptr = strchr(tempS, ',');
    *ptr++ = '.';
    numFiles++;
}

for (; j < numFiles; j++) {
    char *ptr = strchr(tempS, ',');

    //don't know where to go from here...
    fin = openFile(tempS);
    if (fin != NULL) {
        //do something
    }
    fclose(fin);
}
```

It's not done, obviously. I correctly find the number of files, but I'm a little lost when it comes to figuring out how to separate one at a time from the source string and operate on it.

Comment: I'm not looking for regex (or an equally complex solution), either. A simple, mechanical answer is all I'm looking for.

Comment: Since you have already copied the string via `strdup`, try `strtok` on the copy - don't forget to free the copy.

Comment: Use `strtok(str, ",");`. In the first call, `str` is your string, in subsequent calls `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strtok`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) for this

```
char *fname = strtok(tempS, ",");
while (fname != NULL) {
    /* process filename */
    fname = strtok(NULL, ",");
}
```

`strtok` delivers the strings separated by comma, one by one.

Comment: `strtok()` take two `const char*`

Comment: @Jack Thanks for spotting, fixed.

Comment: can I ask why you use NULL for the subsequent calls to strtok?

Comment: @TylerSebastian This is how `strtok` works. You give it the string to split in the first call and NULL in all subsequent calls.

Comment: Ah, it's just that simple, eh... no tricks or whatever, that's just how it was designed.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for splitting string in C, [strok()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok.html) function from C standard library is used.

```
#include <string.h>
...
char *token;
char *line = "string1,string2,string3";
char *search = ",";

token = strtok(line, search);

token = strtok(NULL, search);
```

Answer (score 0):

strtok() is not multithreaded-safe. If that matters to you, you should use strtok_r(). For example:

```
    char *savedptr = NULL /* to be passed back to strtok_r in follow-on calls */
    char *tempS = strdup( some_string ); /* to keep your original intact */
    char *fname = strtok_r(tempS, ",", savedptr);
    while (fname != NULL) {
        /* process fname ... */
        fname = strtok_r(NULL, ",", savedptr); /* pass savedptr back to strtok_r */
    }
```